# Using key-value coding (KVC) to obtain a UIImage but doesn't work when setting picture to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, kvc

My code:

```
for (int index = 1; index < [[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] count] ; index++) {
        NSString *rotaryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotaryImage%d", index];
        UIImage *rotaryWheel = [self.wheelView valueForKey:rotaryName];
        NSString *urlStringImage2 = [[[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
        NSData *imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlStringImage]];
        rotaryWheel =  [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    }
```

However this code works, but it's way too lengthy and looks horrible.

```
        NSString *urlStringImage = [[[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlStringImage]];
        self.wheelView.rotaryImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        NSString *urlStringImage = [[[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlStringImage]];
        self.wheelView.rotaryImage2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Also I would need to do this 12 times!

Comment: try using [self.wheelView setValue:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData] forKey:rotaryName];

Comment: That worked OMG thanks - post as a question so I can upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change as below

```
for (int index = 1; index < [[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] count] ; index++) {
    NSString *rotaryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotaryImage%d", index];
    NSString *urlStringImage2 = [[[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    NSData *imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlStringImage]];
    [self.wheelView setValue:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData] forKey:rotaryName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edited:

```
for (int index = 1; index < [[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] count] ; index++) {
    NSString *rotaryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotaryImage%d", index];

    NSString *urlStringImage2 = [[[firstPageJSONData objectForKey:@"pillars"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    NSData *imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlStringImage]];
    rotaryWheel =  [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

    [[self.wheelView setValue: rotaryWheel forKey: rotaryName];
}
```

Comment: but I want the image of self.wheelView.rotaryImage1 to be the image at the URL link, and now I have an array of images.